# Excel - How to fill a certain amount of cells/rows with the same text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-auto-fill

Imagine you have a random text at the first cell and want to fill the next X cells/rows (e.g: 104 cells) with the same text. Is it a way to solve this without coping-pasting?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Fill Down Ctrl+D, Fill Right Ctrl+R

Answer (score 1):

Select all cells that you want to fill and make sure the first cell is the active cell. Hit F2 to edit the active cell, then hit Ctrl-Enter to enter the same contents into all selected cells.

[image]

Comment: Or you can just drag the bottom right corner down. Works with groups of rows too